# DatePicker xaml Windows Phone 8.1 disable dates

Tags: xaml, datepicker, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I need to disable several dates to be picked with the DatePicker in Windows.Ui.Xaml.Controls. Also I need to make only specific values selectable, for example only the minutes 1, 15, 30 and so on.
Is this possible soemhow?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the built in controls in Windows Phone 8.1, you cannot disable certain dates with the `DatePicker`.  As the UI isn't necessarily linear in that the date can be selected in any order by the user, building a user experience that then prevented certain dates may be confusing. (It's much easier to visualize a disabled date when the full calendar is shown).

You can use the `TimePicker` to set a minute interval to force selection on 15 minute intervals for example using the property [`MinuteIncrement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker.minuteincrement).

If you need more complex date and time selection, you may need to investigate third party options.

Comment: Third party options are unfortuately not available for 8.1 universal apps. I think I will create my own calendar control.